# Value does not fall within the expected range exception when trying to activate a feature

Tags: sharepoint

Hi I am trying to develop a navigation folder content type in SharePoint 2010 as xml format. I strictly followed the Microsoft rules. Even though i am getting the"value doesn't fall within the expected range exception" while i try to activate the feature. Here is the xml snippet i used.

```
<ContentType ID=" 0x012000D53406347378474294E656BB5275621F" Name="Navigation Folder" Group="Navigation ContentTypes" Description="IHS Navigation">
 <FieldRefs>
<FieldRef ID="{D3573D2A-7800-4B42-8A30-F59F85CFD1F8}" Name="ItemOrder" DisplayName="Item Order" Required="TRUE"/>
<FieldRef ID="{BBC9EB6E-A11C-46CC-80D3-28ECAADE06CB}" Name="OpenNewWindow" DisplayName="Open New Window" Required="FALSE"/>
<FieldRef ID="{D5978346-B494-4E94-823E-C40EE6919630}" Name="UrlAudience" DisplayName="Url Audience" Required="FALSE"/>
<FieldRef ID="{47263346-C54D-4055-811B-67755F2B2837}" Name="UrlDescription" DisplayName="Url Description" Required="FALSE" />
<FieldRef ID="{1795B452-70BA-4FAC-A781-4EB593A0954C}" Name="UrlLink" Required="FALSE"/>--> 
</FieldRefs>
</ContentType>
```

The sitecolumns are already activated and column ids are same as that.

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the blank space in ID for Content Type definition.